# create login page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, authentication

it has been many many years since i last touched asp.net and visual studio and i have completely forgotten all about it, but unfortunately i have been tasked to create a "simple" web portal so i need help... lots of help!

i am using sql server 2012 as my db.

name of the db is `DB1`.

username and password data has already been populated in `Table1(username, password)`.

i believe i have somehow managed to setup the connection to the db.

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CapstoneConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

so in my login.aspx page, how do i...

Q1. read the data from user input text fields?

Q2. how do i connect to the db on the aspx page so that i can perform sql query?

Q3. how do i perform the username/password validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my answer here and it comes with sample codes: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/login-page-form-example-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in about two hours.

Drop a Login control onto your page.

Double click on it and in the created method do your SQL authentication. (Make sure you're hashing the password and storing the hash in your database - don't compare the passwords, compare the hashes)

You can inellisense the properties for username and password - it's usually

```
Login1.Username
Login1.Password
```

Call RedirectFromLoginPage when the login is successful.

The control will take care of the invalid password message for you.

Oh, you'll need to set up Forms authentication in your web.config file, and you should also SSL the site since you never want to send a password in clear text.

You should Google "ASP.NET Forms Authentication" for more information. There are TONS of tutorials on this and it's pretty easy to do.

[ASP.NET login controls documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.ASPX)

Comment: due to time constraint i took a glance at the login control and i saw it has username, password, and forgot password. my login page only requires user id, meaning no need password, so login control does not suit it right? and is it possible to change the look of the login control, for example instead of the standard asp login button, can i use a image button?

Comment: You can style the control if you take a look at the output HTML. I believe there are properties for things like the Forgot Password link so you can decide whether to show it or not. In your sample you said your table has username and password fields, so I thought you needed to log in. If you don't, you can still use Forms authentication and instead validate the username exists. You'd follow basically the same pattern (verify the user exists, then redirect from the login page). You'll need to define your login page in web.config, as documented in the link I mentioned.